# I am confused of what a humongous query is?

Tags: algorithm

A subsequence of any 10-string is called humongous if it is of the form `1010...10` (`10` concatenated an arbitrary number of times).

For example, the 10-string `110` contains exactly 2 humongous subsequences and `1010` contains exactly 4 humongous subsequences (formed using indices `{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}`).

Please don't mistake me for asking the solution of this question, I am just asking how many humongous subsequences `10010` has and what are their indices.

Comment: This definition of "humongous" is unknown to me. I would also not describe {1,4} as a subsequence. It is not consecutive. If it is supposed to circle round, then it would be {4,1} and would describe a non-humongous subsequence "01". So the definition as given by you (or at least the examples) seem inconsistent. Is there any source of that definition you can question?

Comment: It seems the inconsistence could be solved by understanding "any subset of characters in same order". E.g. {1,3} would also be considered a subsequence, a non-humongous one though.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: Suppose we consider {1,4} as a subsequence for once, 'cause they are he first and last digits, even then what about {1,3} in 10010 would that be humongous ?

Comment: Maybe you can let us know the source from where you got this information.

Comment: @coderredoc Thank you, i got the answer.

Comment: The combination of the explanation and two examples seems to explain it pretty clearly - I'm not sure that adding another example would help you. Which part of the examples or explanation don't you understand?

Comment: @Dukeling considering '10010', what about the pair of indices {1,3},'cause if we take 1 and 3 we are breaking the sequence right?.Also, how is {1,3} possible in '110',and similarly in '10010' {1,5} must be true according to their explanation.

Comment: [Subsequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) do not need to be consecutive (that would be [substrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring)). That seems to be the main / only point of confusion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just too much fun. Here's a coded answer to your question:

How many humongous subsequences does `10010` have? Click to find out!

```js
function countHumongousSubs(s){
  let count_subs_ending_in_one = 0;
  let count_subs_ending_in_zero = 0;
  
  let i = 0;

  while (s[i]){
    if (s[i] == '1')
      count_subs_ending_in_one += 1 + count_subs_ending_in_zero;
    else
      count_subs_ending_in_zero += count_subs_ending_in_one;
    i++;
  }
  
  return count_subs_ending_in_zero;
}

console.log(countHumongousSubs('10010'));
```

```css
/* https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

And what are their indices? Click to find out!

```js
function humongousSubIndices(s){
  let indices_ending_in_one = [];
  let indices_ending_in_zero = [];
  
  let i = 0;
  
  while (s[i]){
    if (s[i] == '1'){
      indices_ending_in_one =
        indices_ending_in_one.concat(
          indices_ending_in_zero.map(x => x.concat([i+1]))
        );
        
      indices_ending_in_one.push([i+1]);
      
    } else {
      indices_ending_in_zero =
        indices_ending_in_zero.concat(
          indices_ending_in_one.map(x => x.concat([i+1]))
        );
    }
    
    i++;
  }

  return indices_ending_in_zero;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(humongousSubIndices('10010')));
```

```css
/* https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

*(I assume that this is a homework question, asking for a program to count humongous subsequences. I am therefor using the compromise described here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) . I.e. I do not give a full solution of the assignment in code, but propose a way of thinking/interpreting which seems plausible and should allow to go on with the homework.)*

This definition of "humongous" is unknown to me. Let's assume that the definition is by a teacher and only applicable to this question.
It seems that 'any subsequence of alternating "1"s and "0"s which starts with a "1" and ends with a "0"', would be more of a definition, less example-based.

(I would also not describe {1,4} as a subsequence. It is not consecutive.
But that seems to be only my view, as mentioned and supported with a quote by Dukeling.)

Considering a subsequences not needing to be consecutive, e.g. {1,3} would also be considered a subsequence of the example "1010", a non-humongous one though ("11").

With that interpretation of the definition, the count of humongous subsequences of "10010" would be

{1,2}
{1,3}
{1,5}
{4,5}
{1,2,4,5}
{1,3,4,5}

Comment: It's generally assumed that subsequences need not consist of consecutive characters. See also the well-known [Longest increasing subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

Comment: @Dukeling Incorporated your valuable input.

Comment: You're missing {4, 5}